# Null pointer exception on API response retrofit2, despite the response operation being successful

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2

Proplem:

I'm trying to pass the ID parameter to a dialog screen to view the required data by ID. Despite the response process being successfully done as shown in the stack trace, the venue's data always returns a NullPointerException. The same steps in the following lines with this API work perfectly with other parts of the project.

As you can see in this image, the response state is successful, and the API data is already fetched, but it still provides this error.

If anyone can help.

Error:

[![NullPointerException][1]][1]

API Response Steps:

//Dialog Screen

```
@Composable
fun FetchVenueInfo(
    onDismiss: ()-> Unit,
    onConfirm:()->Unit,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        if (!mainViewModel.isVenuesByIdInitialized.value) {
            mainViewModel.getVenuesById(mainViewModel.venueId.value)
            mainViewModel.isVenuesByIdInitialized.value = true
        }
    }
    when (val state = mainViewModel.venuesByIdState.collectAsState().value) {
        is VenuesByIdState.Empty -> {  }
        is VenuesByIdState.Loading -> {  }
        is VenuesByIdState.Error -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, state.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        is VenuesByIdState.Success -> {
            CustomDialog(
                onDismiss = { onDismiss() },
                onConfirm = { onConfirm() },
                venuesResponse = state.data.body()!!
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomDialog(
    onDismiss: ()-> Unit,
    onConfirm:()->Unit,
    venuesResponse: VenuesResponse
) {
    val dark = LocalTheme.current.isDark
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            onDismiss()
        },
        properties = DialogProperties(
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
        )
    ) {
       Card(
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
                .border(
                    2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
                )
       ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(15.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(25.dp)
            ){
                Text(venueResponse.name!!) // <- NullPointerException
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = venuesResponse.image, // <- NullPointerException
                        contentDescription = "Image"
                    )
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

//Opening Dialog onClick

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    matchByIdResponseItem: MatchByIdResponseItem,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    if (mainViewModel.isDialogShown) {
        FetchStadiumInfo(
            onDismiss = { mainViewModel.onDismiss() },
            onConfirm = {}
        )
    }
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(
                 interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                 indication = ripple(
                      bounded = true,
                      color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                 ),
                 onClick = {
                      mainViewModel.setId(matchByIdResponseItem.fixture!!.venue!!.id!!)
                      mainViewModel.onDialogOpened()
                 }
            )
            .padding(top = 1.dp),
       colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = Color.Transparent
       )
    ) {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @BenjyTec 
I have pointed to it in the first code block; it's coming from the text and image from the API. But, as you see, all of the data is successfully retrieved.

Comment: I missed that, thanks for point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, somehow not Venues class, but VenuesResponse is called Response<> by mistake within my code, and then the list will never be fetched. So, simply put, this is my data class: All I did was replace VenuesResponce with Venues in all steps:

```
data class Venues(

    @field:SerializedName("response")
    val response: List<VenuesResponse?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("get")
    val get: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("paging")
    val paging: Paging? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("parameters")
    val parameters: Parameters? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("results")
    val results: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("errors")
    val errors: List<Any?>? = null
)

//ex.
interface MainApi {
    @Headers("api-key: $API_KEY")
    @GET(Constants.GET_VENUES)
    suspend fun getVenuesById(
        @Query(Constants.VENUE_BY_ID_PARAM) id: Int
    ): Response<Venues>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log is only showing that the API is successfully returning data. But it does not give you any hint whether Retrofit/OkHttp/Gson were able to map the response data onto your `Response<VenuesResponse>` class successfully.

You have not provided your `VenuesResponse` class, but it could happen that if there is a mismatch in the field names or in the hierarchy of the JSON response and your Kotlin classes, all fields will set to `null`.

I would recommend that you update your log statement as follows:

```
Log.d("Tag", "Success: $venueByIdResponse ")
```

and check whether the values are already null at that point.

---

Also, make sure that you use the correct variable names. It is probably just a typo, but

```
Text(venueResponse.name!!)
```

shouldn't even compile, as `venueResponse` does not exist, it should be `venuesResponse`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check now

Comment: I have modified the question and attached a picture showing the response.